# Navigation in Jetpack Compose. Button onClick issue

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have some program with 2 screens made in Compose.
One of this screen have a button that makes transmission to another screen.
All works good, if I put only this action on this Button's onClick method.
But if I try to add something else, that should be made before changing screen, this navigate function no work anymore.

This way works:

```
Button(
    onClick = onNavigateToListUser
) {
    Text(text = "Add")
}
```

This way does not:

```
        Button(
            onClick = {
                if (firstName != "" && lastName != "") {
                    val user = User(uid = 555, firstName, lastName)
                    userDao.insert(user)
                    Log.d("MyDebug", ":" + user.firstName + " " + user.lastName)
                }
                Log.d("MyDebug", "Hey. Second Line")
                onNavigateToListUser
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Add")
        }
```

What is onNavigate...:

```
composable(route = DatabaseScreens.AddData.name) {
                AddDataScreen(
                    userDao,
                    onNavigateToListUser = { navController.navigate(DatabaseScreens.UserList.name) }
                )
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined the function `doSomething: () -> Unit`, you can use:

```
   onClick = doSomething
   onClick = { doSomething() }
```

In your 2nd case you have to use:

```
    onClick = {
          //if () { /* ... */ }
          onNavigateToListUser() //instead of onNavigateToListUser
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second code

```kotlin
onClick = {
    ...
    onNavigateToListUser
}
```

Kotlin's lambda function regards the last line as the returned value, so this one actually returns a lambda function(`onNavigateToListUser`) instead of executing it. You need to call it dirictly.

```kotlin
onClick = {
    ...
    onNavigateToListUser()
    // or onNavigateToListUser.invoke()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You are the place number two)